# Programmatically short GPIO pins Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

For a hobby I'm working on a project connecting a RF remote to the raspberry pi.

When I press a button, pin 13 and 14 are shorted on the MCU.

When I put a jumper cable between the pins, the remote sends it's message.

Now the following:

Pin 13 and 14 are connected to GPIO 0 and 1.

In what state should I put the GPIO pins to simulate the same behaviour?

Should I read data from one pin, and send it to the other one or something?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: a) Do you expect the 'connection' between the GPIOs to carry substantial current? b) Can one of the pins be identified as input and the other as output? c) Is the signal digital in nature? d) How fast do you expect a change at one pin to be reflected at the other pin?

Comment: When I put a multimeter between the pins, there is a very little flow from one of the pins to the other. Like 0,002 V but it's steady. So I can identify an input and output pin. EDIT: I measured again: 0.000V so no flow. I don't know how the MCU knows there is a connection between the pins.

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions.

Comment: There is almost nothing I know about the connection. Only both pins are at 3.15V. The switch connects the two pins together so the remote fires the event. How can the MCU know the pins are connected when the current on both pins is the same?

Comment: Why use two GPIO pins to convey one bit of information? What is the MCU; the Pi, or the Remote, or something else? Is the Pi supposed to *send* or *receive* the message via GPIO?

Comment: Because that is all the material I have, no transistor, octocoupler or relais. To be clear: the remote has a mcu that handles button presses. The pi is a minicomputer on which Im able to switch GPIO ports. I connect the MCU pins to the Pi GPIO ports to simulate button presses. On one pin it works, it's connected to GND. This one doesn't work because it's connected to another pin. What I want to do is simulate the behaviour of the pin to pin connection. They are both at 3.15 Volts so I don't see how the MCU knows they are connected.

Comment: Is one of the pins by any chance (connected to) the power of that MCU?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "short" a circuit using only GPIO as far as I know (keep in mind I'm quite new to this). What you're looking for is a NPN transistor.

Take a look here: http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits - Output circuits using NPN transistor.

You then connect 2 pins on MCU to collector and emitter on transistor, and when you set HIGH on GPIO it should conduct current (*short*).

PS. Are you sure both Pin 3 and 14 that you short are powered? one of them should be ground.